# Mostrar result grid no mysql Workbench

Tags: query, mysql

Ao executar consultas no meu MYSQL WorkBench, não consigo ver a Result Grid, apenas a tela de output dizendo se houve erro ao executar o comando ou não.

Como posso ativar a aba do Result Grid para visualizar a tabela?

Segue print para melhor entendimento. Essa é a aba que aparece no lugar do Result Grid.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou clicar logo acima da barra "Output" pra ver se a janela não está escondida no rodapé?

Comment: Sim, já tentei, nada acontece.